# Custom cumulative sum in php

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, inner-join, cumulative-sum

I have had success with cumulative sum in php mysql.

```
+---+---------+
| id| SomeNumt|
+---+---------+
|  1|       10|
|  2|       12|
|  3|        3|
|  4|       15|
|  5|       23|
+---+---------+

SELECT t1.id,
       t1.SomeNumt,
       SUM(t2.SomeNumt) AS SUM
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id,
         t1.SomeNumt
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Output:

```
+---+---------+--------+
| id| SomeNumt|     SUM|
+---+---------+--------+
|  1|       10|      10|
|  2|       12|      22|
|  3|        3|      25|
|  4|       15|      40|
|  5|       23|      63|
+---+---------+--------+
```

Now I have a little problem, when I custom query (`WHERE t1.SomeNumt>3`)

```
...
INNER JOIN t t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
WHERE t1.SomeNumt>3
...
```

Out put is wrong

```
+---+---------+--------+
| id| SomeNumt|     SUM|
+---+---------+--------+
|  1|       10|      10|
|  2|       12|      22|
|  4|       15|      40|
|  5|       23|      63|
+---+---------+--------+
```

But I was expecting:

```
+---+---------+--------+
| id| SomeNumt|     SUM|
+---+---------+--------+
|  1|       10|      10|
|  2|       12|      22|
|  4|       15|      37|   -- 10+22+15
|  5|       23|      60|   -- 10+22+15+23
+---+---------+--------+
```

How to fix?

Comment: Why is this tagged with java a php? We also have no idea what your SQL tables look like or what they have in them?

Comment: In order to fix we need to know whats wrong. SQL did what you told it to do. Tell us what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't understand. You're telling it you only want results where `t1.SomeNumt>3`, and that's what your're getting. Kindly edit your Question with clarification, do not provide those in comments. If you expect the result of the sum to be different, please explain exactly why and how you expect it to be calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the same condition to `t2`:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.SomeNumt,
       SUM(t2.SomeNumt) AS SUM
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
WHERE t1.SomeNumt > 3 AND t2.SomeNumt > 3
GROUP BY t1.id,
         t1.SomeNumt
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Alternatively you can apply the condition in a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.SomeNumt,
       SUM(t2.SomeNumt) AS SUM
FROM (SELECT * FROM t WHERE SomeNumt > 3) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM t WHERE SomeNumt > 3) t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id,
         t1.SomeNumt
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Output (for both queries):

```
id  SomeNumt    SUM
1   10          10
2   12          22
4   15          37
5   23          60
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x3zbsyorkvuugSEYu49oEp/1)

If you're using MySQL 8+, you should use window functions as described in @GordonLinoff's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cumulative sum use window functions:

```
SELECT t.id, t.SomeNumt,
       SUM(t2.SomeNumt) OVER (ORDER BY t.id) AS SUM
FROM t
ORDER BY t.id;
```

If you add a `WHERE` clause, this should then do what you want.